# ¿Cómo soluciono este error utlizando print spider.lastUrl()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este es mi código, es para un buscador en Python:

```
# -*- coding utf-8 *-*
import chilkat
import MySQLdb

spider = chilkat.CkSpider()

spider.Initialize("https://www.python.org/")

spider.AddUnspidered("https://www.python.org/")

for i in range(0,300):

success = spider.CrawlNext()

if (success==True):
    print spider.lastUrl()
    print spider.lastHtmlTitle()
    print spider.lastHtmlDescription()
    print spider.lastHtmlKeywords()

Host='127.0.0.1'
usuario='root'
pass='root'
db_name='buscador'

def ejecute_query(query=''):
    datos=(Host, usuario, password, db_name)

    conn=MySQLdb.connect(*datos)
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)


    if query.upper().startswith('SELECT'):
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    else:
        conn.commit()
        data=None

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return data


 url = spider.lastUrl()
 titulo = spider.lastHtmlTitle()
 pclav = spider.lastHtmlKeywords()
 descripcion = spider.lastHtmlDescription()
 visitas ='1'


 dato = (url, titulo, pclav, descripcion, visitas)

query="INSERT INTO  autos (url, titulo, pclav, descripcion, visitas) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"%dato

ejecute_query(query)

else:
if (spider.getNumUnspidered==0):
    print"No hay mas direcciones URL para rastrear"
else:
    print spider.lastErrorText()


spider.sleepMs(10)
```

Cuando lo ejecuto tengo este error:

> ```
> File "crawler.py", line 16
> print spider.lastUrl()
>            ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: José he intentado responderte pero es complicado darte una respuesta segura dado que la identación de tu código tiene muchos errores. Por favor, te recomiendo copiar el código exactamente como lo tienes y formatearlo adecuadamente (lo seleccionas y pulsas el botón `{}` del editor o Ctrl+K) para preservar la identación y la legibilidad del código. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay unos cuantos errores en el código:

- La identación no es correcta en gran parte del código. Dado que Python usa la identación para delimitar los bloques de código es vital su correcta utilización, además de por cuestiones de legibilidad del código.
- [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print) en Python 3 (que es lo que usas por la etiqueta y porque usas `*` para desempaquetar una lista) **es una función**. Por lo tanto tienes que llamarla:

  ```
  print(spider.lastUrl())
  ```

  en vez de :

  ```
  print spider.lastUrl()
  ```
- `pass` es una palabra reservada en Python, no puedes usarla como nombre de variable. Además, en la función donde haces la consulta no usas `pass` sino `password`.

El código debería ser algo así:

> **Aviso:** dado que la identación es incorrecta es solo una suposición al no poder establecer los bloques de código con seguridad. El código siguente carece de errores de sintaxis pero puede diferir en cuanto a lógica de lo que quieres hacer.

```
# -*- coding utf-8 *-*
import chilkat
import MySQLdb


host = '127.0.0.1'
usuario = 'root'
password = 'root'
db_name = 'buscador'

def ejecute_query(query=''):
    datos=(host, usuario, password, db_name)
    conn=MySQLdb.connect(*datos)
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    if query.upper().startswith('SELECT'):
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    else:
        conn.commit()
        data=None

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return data

spider = chilkat.CkSpider()
spider.Initialize("https://www.python.org/")
spider.AddUnspidered("https://www.python.org/")

for i in range(300):
    success = spider.CrawlNext()
    if success:
        print(spider.lastUrl())
        print(spider.lastHtmlTitle())
        print(spider.lastHtmlDescription())
        print(spider.lastHtmlKeywords())

        url = spider.lastUrl()
        titulo = spider.lastHtmlTitle()
        pclav = spider.lastHtmlKeywords()
        descripcion = spider.lastHtmlDescription()
        visitas ='1'

        dato = (url, titulo, pclav, descripcion, visitas)
        query="INSERT INTO  autos (url, titulo, pclav, descripcion, visitas) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"%dato
        ejecute_query(query)

    else:
        if (spider.getNumUnspidered==0):
            print("No hay mas direcciones URL para rastrear")
        else:
            print(spider.lastErrorText())

    spider.sleepMs(10)
```

En vez de crear una conexión a la base de datos y un nuevo cursor cada vez que obtienes un resultado a guardar deberias considerar crear la conexión y el cursor al inicio del script y en el buble `for` solo realizar las peticiones necesarias y al terminar la ejecución cierras la conexión.